# react-native code push: allowable code change?

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I'm using react-native-code-push for my app. 
I had released several versions that change only a few of js bugs, which worked fine.

Recently I realized that if a code pushed release involves any change of native code other than javascript, the app crashes while updating. I added several react native packages that need manual linking such as react-native-maps, and released update to some targeted versions hoping them to take those, but no luck.

Then what if an update only involves adding light libraries (using npm install) which don't require native linking? I wonder to what extent exactly the code push allows client-side code updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, when you want to add some native code involving `link` you will have to rebuild your apk / ipa and re-upload it to the stores. If you want to add a new plugin without `link` there should not be any problem

One advice I could give is to only push bug fixes to your production app. You should not push new features with codepush since apple review (almost) all the applications.

Comment: Lets say you push native code changes to appstore, and then another bugfix to codepush, but the user doesn't download the appstore update. Will codepush download the next bugfix and then crash (since the native changes haven't been downloaded) ?

Comment: In order to debug efficiently, Im using the expo channels (might be in codepush but not sure) ex: you got prod-v1 on user phone, you want to update to prod-v2, so you only publish to prod-v2  and users with prod-v1 are not affected. If you publish a bugfix to prod-v2, the user without the last version installed will have no changes.